# On writing a gulp file that can do CLI commands

Tags: python, django, angularjs

I'm sure this is a simple problem but I can't seem to write up a gulpfile that'll do this. I'm trying to figure out a gulpfile that can do the following tasks:

```
1. Install Bower dependencies onto the computer
2. Install AngularJS dependencies 
3. Run the "python manage.py runserver" command for the Django web framework.
```

How would one write the gulpfile for it? Which gulp plugins would I use to do this?

Comment: Do you use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html)?

Comment: Yes I do use a virtual env but I don't see that being an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to run Bower commands within your Gulp file, without going to the command line. Here's one way, adapted from https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/82854/Gulp-task-to-run-bower-install-update-an

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bower = require('bower');
var _ = require('lodash');

gulp.task('bower', function() {
  var deps = _.chain(require(bower.config.cwd + '/bower.json').dependencies).keys().value();
  bower.commands['install'](deps);
});
```

But there are easier ways. You can probably get where you want to be with a combination of:

- `gulp-shell`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell
- `gulp-install`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-install